# Type system vs dynamic check

Tags: java, type-systems

I'm studying about type systems and I encountered the following exercise:

> ```
> interface Food{}
>
> interface Plant extends Food{
>     void photosyntes();
> }
>
> interface Animal extends Food{
>     void eat(Food food);
> }
> ```
>
> - We'd like to implement interface `Carnivore`, extending `Animal`. Its `eat` method will accept only instances of Animal. This restriction should be enforced by the type system, not by a dynamic check. Explain why this cannot be done using the above interface definition.
> - In Java, the array type `Animal[]` is a subtype of `Food[]`. In general if S is a subtype of T, then S[] is a subtype of T[]. This rule requires that a runtime type check be performed at each array store. Describe a situation where, if this runtime check were not performed, an array of `Animal[]` could contain a `Plant`. Illustrate with Java code.

My intuition is that this problem is related to covariance and contravariance, but I can't come up with an exhaustive explanation.

Is it because we must use classes instead of interfaces? Is it possible to use a different interface system to allow that?